# django-admin startproject not working

Tags: python, django

I have created django file using django-admin startproject command and the file was saved in C drive, but I can't find that file in C drive.

So I again created django file with same name and it gives error :

**CommandError: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\website' already exists**

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your project inside your user directory and not in Windows.

```
cd c:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop
mkdir Project
cd Project
django-admin startproject projectname
```

Comment: I have already created project with another name but the problem still remains the same, I can't find that file in C drive

Comment: Create a project directory, and then startproject in that directory.

Comment: Can you please help me with changing the directory, coz i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Use the first command in `command prompt` just enter your `username`

Comment: I have changed directory and created a django project. Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: @Vallabh, It is pleasing to hear that, if the solution helped you. Please select the answer.Thanks for all the cooperation.